# SQL SSIS handling of quotation marks in content - 2008R2 vs. 2014 difference?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

Dears,

I had some confusing behaviour regarding SSIS import of CSV files. My conclusion is strange but seems the only explanation.

SSIS on SQL Server 2008 R2 worked fine.
SSIS on SQL Server 2014 fails: "column identifier not found".

It turns out the CSV file was at fault, and SSIS 2008 never picked up on this.

Quotation marks within fields are not 'doubled' as per standard practice.

currently: "title", "milestone "completion of work""
should be: "title", "milestone ""completion of work"""

After much investigation, it seems that the difference is SSIS 2014.

If I execute the package (exact same package on the exact same old 2008 server), but using SSIS 2014, I receive the error.

Conclusion:  SSIS 2014 reads CSV files differently, and (correctly) throws an error where SSIS 2008 for some reason didn't.

Is there any other option or way that SSIS 2014 can be run to overcome this problem? Or do I have to wait until they correct the original CSV file encoding?

I hope that was clear, and many thanks for your inputs.

Comment: ssis 2012 introduced proper support for "embedded text qualifiers". I'm not sure if there is a way of turning it off and getting support for the old behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue back in 2012.  Files would import without error in 2008 but the data would be corrupted in the few records that were not correct.  This changed to throwing an error and stopped our processes from completing.

If you search long enough you might find a better workaround but here are the choices I came up with at the time:
1.  Read in the entire line into a staging table and parse the CSV with custom code.
2.  Use a third party tool.

We choose #2 and in particular http://www.csvreader.com/

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback Joe, and confirming my findings.  I'm going with option 3:  wait for the providers to fix it. They already confirmed the bug and that it will be corrected, so no point me writing any more code now.  cheers!